# Getting consecutive numbers without repetition

Tags: r, random, numbers

From a random sequence of numbers {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}, it is asked to determine the number of times that groups of 3 consecutive numbers appear, it means, the number of times that have been generated with the base = c ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5") any of the following groups {"123", "234", "345" }.

```
# I undertand that I have generate a sample with 5 numbers
a<-c(sample(1:5,5))
a
#I generated the list, as you can see I didn't fix a seed because I know that in every single sequence I will have differents grupos of 3 consecutive numbers, so I should obtain something like this

b<-c(2,3,4,5,1) #this example gives me just one that it would be {2,3,4}
b
#answer expected
1
#Then, I don't know how to obtain the sequence I have tried with permutations and combinations but I don't get it.
```

Comment: Do you count the groups with overlap? If you have a sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, would you have a count for 123, 234, 345? Or just 1 for 123?

Comment: {2,4,5} are not consecutive. They are merely increasing. Which do you want,  consecutive or increasing?

Comment: Does "consecutive" include wrap-around?  451, 512?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will count any occurrence of a three item increasing streak (e.g. 123).

```
countsequence <- function(x){
  if (length(x)<3){
    return(0)
  }
  count <- 0
  for(i in 3:length(x)){
    if(x[i-1]==x[i]-1 && x[i-2] == x[i]-2){
      count <- count + 1
    }
  }
  return(count)
} 

countsequence(1:5)
countsequence(c(2, 3, 4, 1, 5))
```

Comment: if it is meant to be consecutive and not increasing, use the if statement as follows: `if(x[i-1]< x[i] && x[i-2] < x[i-1]){`

Answer (score 0):

Parameter `k` is for subsequence length (in your case 3):

```
f <- function(b, k = 3){

  if(k > length(b)) return(0)
  
  check_list <- lapply(k:length(b), function(x) all(diff(b[(x-k+1):x]) == 1)) 
  sum(unlist(check_list))
}
```

If you want to count increasing or decreasing subsequences replace `==` and `1` with appropriate relation and number.